# Can I do this without a server?

Tags: javascript, html

I have no backend skills yet, i'm just trying to find out if I can create this functionality using javascript and run it on my browser.

I want a birthday input field, and a submit button.

I want to take the birthday data, and add all the individual numbers together, and then add the digits of that sum to get a single digit.

For example:

10/9/1940 would calculate 1+0+9+1+9+4+0. Which would equal 24. Then it would add the digits 2+4. Which equals 6.

Then, I want to print that number at the end of an h1 that says, "your combined birthday number is: 6"

Any tips? I dont have any idea how to link the input data in a birthday form to a submit button.

Comment: No, you don't need a server for this.

Comment: First, you would want to write a javascript function that would compute the number you want out of a birthdate.  You could try this shell to write/test your code: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Tools/Scratchpad
Then, you could look up how to hook up JavaScript functions to an input field in a form via the "onclick" event handler.

Comment: Thanks. if you can, could you explain to me how to link together a submit button with the input data from a birthday form? I know how to create a date form, and also create a button. But how do I capture the date data, and link it to that submit button? I know that i can add an eventListener to the button, and write a function that does the logic. But not sure about how to get that value linked to the button.

Answer (score 4):

Yes - if you do not need information to persist beyond a reload of the page, then you can do almost anything with JavaScript. Your use case is not that different from [W3Schools' JS tutorial](https://www.w3schools.com/js/) - besides a button, the form would just need a date entry field, and a few lines to do your calculation and apply the changes to the page. I recommend going through that to get an idea of the possibilities.

A server is only required if you want a system to act autonomously or remember across multiple users.

Comment: Thanks, I guess I'm just confused then about how to capture the date data, and then run a function using that data.

Comment: Depending on the amount of data top store, couldn't you asleep same info to a cookie in the user's browser and retrieve that later, without needing a server?

Comment: @nineborn Fair point, other answers here have provided implementations.

Comment: @BruceWayne Yes, the server is only needed for multiple users or across devices. Though if it's just one date, I would leave it to the browser's form filler.

Answer (score 1):

Try this way using [parseInt()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseInt) to check if its a number.

```js
function sumString(str, result) {
  for (i = 0; i < str.length; i++)
    if (!isNaN(parseInt(str[i])))
      result += parseInt(str[i]);
  if (result.toString().length <= 1)
    return result;
  else
    return sumString(result.toString(), 0);
}


function onBirthDaySelect(value) {
  document.getElementById('result').innerHTML = `<h1>your combined birthday number is: ${sumString(value, 0)}</h1>`;
}
```

```html
<input type="date" id="bday"> <button onclick="onBirthDaySelect(document.getElementById('bday').value)">Calculate</button>
<div id="result"></div>
```

Comment: thanks for this but this is way outside my knowledge. Not even sure how to read some of this syntax, though it may be perfect i just cant tell.

Comment: there isn't anything fancy here. The `parseInt()` is used to check if the given input is an integer or not, for your case, it will return false for `/`

Comment: I see what you're saying. How is this function linked to the input data though? if I write a simple date form: 

 <input type="date" name="bday">

Then how do I even capture that data to begin with? Sorry if this is obvious Im just not following how to even extract that data to begin running a function with it.

Comment: for that, you need to define the `onchange()` for your input and you can get the value from `input.value` which can be passed to this function. I have updated the code, please check.

Comment: Can I extract the value somehow from the DOM? If I added an id tag, and then selected it using the DOM (and save it to a variable) can I manipulate the variable somehow in a function to achieve my goal here? 

Such as: HTML: <input type="date" name="bday" id = "birthday>
JS: var birthday = document.getElementById("#birthday");

Would I then be able to manipulate that value, or do i still need to somehow convert it into strictly a number first. Am i on the right track?

Comment: yes you can, `var birthday = document.getElementById("#birthday")` and `birthday.value` will get the value for you. Have edited the post to inlcude this as well

Comment: as it is, the h1 appears as i'm typing in a value into the input. I want it to be hidden until i click on the "calculate" button. And the button seems irrelevant it doesn't do anything.

Also, i need it to reduce to a single digit, this will only get me a 2 digit sum.

Any thoughts?

Comment: yep, for that you just need to remove `onchange="onBirthDaySelect(this.value)"` so it does to fire automatically. What do you mean by single digit?

Comment: well this logic will reduce the data down to a 2 digit number. But i want to reduce it all the way down to one number. So say for example your logic gives me 26. i want to add 2+6 and reduce it further to a single digit of 8.

Comment: so what happens it you get 99 ?

Comment: well ok, i want to write a function which will continue to reduce the sum down until it is a single digit. make sense?

Comment: you can recursively call the same function, please check the edited answer.

Comment: @nineborn please feel free to accept the answer if the solution has solved the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Using Javascript you can parse the Date from the birthday input field, see js string methods, after parsing the string into a number you can easily add them up then put back into your page.

Comment: I guess what I dont understand is, if I create a simple date form:

 <input type="date" name="bday">

Obviously, even if I input a date, there is no output. So how do I even capture that data to begin with, let alone run it in a function?

Comment: First, understand the basic syntax then connect HTML tags and JS, then the example below what others are suggesting becomes easy it answers the requirement you want.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can. By using [input date](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input/date) you can get the date then you convert the value into integer by using [Number()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number) for each index and finally you append the `<h1>` text into body by using 
 [appendChild](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/appendChild):

```js
function calculate(){
  const date = document.getElementById('birthdate').value; // get input date value
  let result = 0; // for each function call set result to 0
  for (let index=0; index < date.length; index++){
    if(Number(date[index])){ // check if number
      result += Number(date[index]); // accumulate result
    }
  }
  const node = document.createElement("h1"); // Create a <h1> node
  const textnode = document.createTextNode(`your combined birthday number is: ${result}`);
  node.appendChild(textnode); // Append the text to <h1>
  document.body.appendChild(node); // Append <h1> to <body>
}
```

```html
<input type="date" id="birthdate">
<button onclick="calculate()">Calculate</button>
```

Server is typically used to store data, and manage the data so you can use them across multiple devices. Which in this case you don't really need one.